# ASIHTTPRequest and ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, iphone, upload, asihttprequest

I need to upload files from iPhone to my ASP.NET server and found ASIHTTPRequest to be an easy tool.

My question is he server part on the ASP.NET. How do I prepare the server part?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out this answer to a similar question about sending image data from Flash to ASP.NET

[How do I Pass an Image from Flash to ASP.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/928508/pass-image-from-flash-to-asp-net/1688492#1688492)