# bitmapdata object from AS3 to a aspx page

Tags: asp.net, flash, actionscript-3

How can i send a Actionscript 3.0 BitmapData object data to a "asp" page.

I need to send an image data (bitmapdata) to a aspx page. Image is taken from a webcam in actionscript 3.0. How can be this done in AS 3.0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this answer will help you:
[How do I Pass an Image from Flash to ASP.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/928508/pass-image-from-flash-to-asp-net/1688492#1688492)

> To send a generated image like this from Flash to ASP.NET (or any
>   other backend) you’re going to need a couple of 3rd party libraries.
>   We’ll need a JPEG Encoder (which Flash doesn’t have, but recent
>   versions of Flex do) which we can get from the AS3 Core Lib
>   http://code.google.com/p/as3corelib/.

Comment: @Mattias...thanks!!! for the reply... it really helped a lot. can you help with one more question? its really urgent... [link]http://www.actionscript.org/forums/showthread.php3?p=1097484#post1097484" here is the post... can you please reply the answer in this forum... its urgent if you don't mind...