# Base64 encoder library download assitance

Tags: asp.net, flash, actionscript

I am referring to [Send image from flash to Asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/928508/how-do-i-pass-an-image-from-flash-to-asp-net) for sending image captured by a webcam to an asp.net page. However I need to download base64 encoder to proceed. The link the user provided for downloading it seems to be broken. Can anyone tell me how I can download the base64 encoder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the fastest Base64 implementation in Flash today: http://www.blooddy.by/en/crypto/ it's about order of magnitude faster then Adobe's libraries. It is written using so called Alchemy opcodes.

There was an interesting attempt at improving AS3-only Base64 algorithm here: http://jpauclair.net/2012/01/12/updated-the-optimized-bas64-library/ . It would probably win in the long run because of maintenance. Adobe has decided to change the old "Alchemy opcodes" in the new player versions, and the author of the blooddy library is no longer actively working on it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe Flash has inbuilt an base64 encoder and decoder. See

- [mx.utils.Base64Encoder](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/utils/Base64Encoder.html)
- [mx.utils.Base64Decoder](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/utils/Base64Decoder.html)

Also, the [AS3Crypto](http://code.google.com/p/as3crypto/) library has Base64 utilities.

I don't know what is being done in the reference you gave, but between these 3 resources, you should get what you are looking for.